# Why it is necessary to mention http while redirecting

Tags: asp.net

I have done a sample code to redirect to google by clicking on an hyperlink

This one worked fine

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="MyHyperLinkControl" NavigateUrl="http://google.com""
    runat="server">link</asp:HyperLink>
```

But this does not work

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="MyHyperLinkControl" NavigateUrl="www.google.com" 
    runat="server">link</asp:HyperLink>
```

Can any one give me a detail explanation please

Answer (score 3):

`NavigateUrl="relative-path"` goes to `./relative-path`, meaning that if your browser is currently at `http://www.example.com/test`, that link will tell it to go to `http://www.example.com/test/relative-path`.

Therefore, `NavigateUrl="www.google.com"` will go to `http://www.example.com/test/www.google.com`.

If, however, you specify a full URL, like `NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com/"`, then you will get to `http://www.google.com/`.

---

To illustrate:

If you have a hyperlink on a page, and that page is located at `http://www.example.com/test`:

```
example.html      goes to   http://www.example.com/test/example.html
example           goes to   http://www.example.com/test/example
google.html       goes to   http://www.example.com/test/google.html
www.google.html   goes to   http://www.example.com/test/www.google.html
www.google.com    goes to   http://www.example.com/test/www.google.com
```

The fact that it's called `www.google.com` makes it no different from any other link.

If you use absolute links (links that start with a `/`), you will get the following behavior:

```
/example.html     goes to   http://www.example.com/example.html
/example          goes to   http://www.example.com/example
/google.html      goes to   http://www.example.com/google.html
/www.google.html  goes to   http://www.example.com/www.google.html
/www.google.com   goes to   http://www.example.com/www.google.com
```

If however you specify the full URL, including schema, then the whole URL from the address bar is replaced with what your full URL points to. For example:

```
mailto:test@example.com  uses the email client
http://www.google.com    uses the browser, pointing it to that URL
```

Comment: I am using hyperlink na not href

Comment: The `NavigateUrl` attribute is where the link points to. I gave an example with `<a/>` for simplicity. Replace "`<a href`" in my example with "`<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl`".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing its because it treats the URL as a relative one and so if you're  currently on page: www.yourdomain.com/ the second will try and navigate to www.yourdomain.com/www.google.com. However if you put the http in front you are telling the link that it should be an absolute link,
You may have a link in your app which goes to test.pdf.old (as an example). You would then not expect it to go to http://test.pdf.old.

WWW is not a keyword meaning this is an external webpage - its essentially a convention. So what if the pdf example above was called www. You would still want to download it and not go to http://www.pdf.old.